# How can I configure the interpolation for a self hosted instance of Pelias?

Tags: maps, interpolation, configuration-files, pelias

I use the [dockerfiles GitHub repository of Pelias](https://github.com/pelias/dockerfiles) and would like to set up a local instance of the geocoding service. I need to import data of Berlin, Germany. To achieve this I have to adjust the data pathes and files in a config file called [pelias.json](https://github.com/pelias/dockerfiles/blob/master/pelias.json). The interpolation part is the following:

```
"interpolation": {
  "download": {
    "tiger": {
      "datapath": "/data/tiger",
      "states": [
        {
          "state_code": 41
        }
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

I know that 'tiger' is a dataset only relevant for the US. But does anybody know how to specify the [interpolation](https://github.com/pelias/interpolation#running-a-build-in-the-docker-container) for Berlin, Germany instead of Portland, Oregon?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also i.a. use data from `openstreetmap` and `openaddresses`, see https://github.com/pelias/interpolation/ . I use docker `pelias/docker` myself. Snippet from `pelias.json`:

> "interpolation": {
>           "datapath": "/data/interpolation/"
>   }

where in `/data/interpolation/` these files resides: `street.db` and `address.db`. How to produce these files is explained in the `pelias/interpolation/` repo.